# Wordpress in Google App Engine gets stuck (Saving search indexes)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run the application but it gets stuck in the last line:

```
2013-11-14 03:05:49 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'F:\\Gabriel\\Desktop\\SITE\\app_engine\\first']"
INFO     2013-11-14 03:05:51,467 devappserver2.py:661] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2013-11-14 03:05:51,502 api_server.py:139] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49409
INFO     2013-11-14 03:05:51,506 api_server.py:529] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-11-14 03:05:51,506 api_server.py:532] Saving search indexes
```

I really don't know what's happening. I followed all the instructions of the app engine tutorial.

I'm using Wamp Server which contains the following modules:

Apache Version :
2.4.4
PHP Version :
5.4.16
MySQL Version :
5.6.12

To create the database, I used sqlbuddy bundled with Wamp Server.

Besides, I deployed the app, but if I try to access through appspot URL I receive the error "Error establishing a database connection".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar issue when I used reg expressions like

```
- url: /restcalls/(*.php)
  script: restcalls/\1.php
```

in YAML file. So,I have removed this and have written separately for individual URLs.